# No me deja llamar datos de diferentes rutas Node.js

Tags: nodejs, handlebars.js

Hola intentare explicar el problema, tengo problemas con al ruta y quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de cambiar este error. Este es mi codigo de configuración en la parte de rutas el problema es que cuando adelanto

```
//llamar modulos
const express = require('express')
const morgan = require('morgan')
const path = require('path')
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars')
const methodOverride = require('method-override')
const session = require('express-session')
const flash = require('connect-flash')
const passport = require('passport')

//incializar
const app = express()
require('./config/database')
require('./config/passport')
//setting
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({
    defaultLayout: 'principal',
    layoutsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'layouts'),
    partialsDir: path.join(app.get('views'), 'partials'),
    extname: '.hbs'
}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');
//middleware
app.use(morgan('dev'))
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
app.use(session({
    secret: 'mysecretapp',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
}))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())
app.use(flash())
//Variables globales - Ejemplo: mensajes de error
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.locals.success_msg = req.flash('success_msg')
    res.locals.error_msg = req.flash('error_msg')
    res.locals.user = req.user
    next()
})
//Rutas

app.use(require('./routes/registro'))
app.use(require('./routes/users'))
app.use(require('./routes/proyecto'))
app.use(require('./routes/notes'))

app.use(require('./routes/index'))

//archivos estaticos
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
//escuchar servidor
app.listen(app.get('port'), () => {
    console.log('Server en el puerto', app.get('port'))
})
```

Lo que ocurre es que cuando llamo los hbs que necesito ellos vienen pero sin la información de la base de datos. en este caso los que me crean conflicto sin services y portafolio

```
<html>
  {{> navegacion}}
     {{> about}}
    {{> services}}
    {{> portafolio}} 
</html>
```

Este es el html de services

```
<div class="row">
            {{#each notes}}
            <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 wow fadeIn" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <!-- Single Service -->
                <div class="single-service active">
                    <i class="fa fa-html5"></i>
                    <h2>{{title}}</h2>
                    <p>{{description}}</p>
                </div>
                <!-- End Single Service -->
            </div>
            {{/each}}
        </div>
```

Este es el de protafolio

```
{{#each images}}
                    <div class="mix development html5 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-fix ">
                        <div class="portfolio-single">
                            <div class="portfolio-head">
                                <img src="{{path}}" alt="" />
                            </div>
                            <div class="portfolio-hover">
                                <h4><span>Web Design</span><a href="#">{{title}}</a></h4>
                                <p>{{description}}</p>
                                <div class="button">
                                    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="{{path}}"><i
                                            class="fa fa-search"></i></a>
                                    <a href="portfolio-single.html" class="primary"><i class="fa fa-link"></i></a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {{/each}}
```

al final lo que ocurre es que el objeto images no me trae nada y el objeto images si me trae la informaciónd e la base de datos pero el de notes no esto depende de en que posicion ponga si uno primero que el otro espero que me pudieran entender perdon si no

Consulta a la BD de image

```
const { Schema, model } = require('mongoose')

const imageSchema = new Schema({
 title: {type: String},
 description: {type: String},
 filename: {type: String},
 path: {type: String}, 
 originalname: {type: String},
 mimetype: {type: String},
 size: {type: Number},
created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now()}
})

module.exports = model('Image', imageSchema)
```

consulta a la BD de notes

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { Schema } = mongoose;
const NoteSchema = new Schema({
    title: { type: String, require: true },
    description: { type: String, require: true },
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Note', NoteSchema)
```

Aqui se crean los objetos de notes

```
router.get('/index', async (req, res) => {
    await Note.find().sort({ date: 'desc' })
        .then(documentos => {
            const contexto = {
                notes: documentos.map(documento => {
                    return {
                        title: documento.title,
                        description: documento.description,
                        date: documento.date,
                        _id: documento._id
                    }
                })
            }
            res.render('partials/services', {
                notes: contexto.notes
            })
        })
})
```

aqui se crean los objetos de image

```
router.get('/index', async (req, res) => {
    const images = await Image.find().lean()
   /*  console.log(images) */
    res.render('proyectos/proyecto', { images: images })

})
```

Comment: O si perdon no postre la consulta ya pongo el codigo al final lo pondre de ambos